# Increase delay in transition speed of hiding Navbar when scrolling down using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am new to HTML, CSS and JS. I am making a homepage using Bootstrap-5. I have implemented navbar in my page. The problem is that navbar hides so quickly when I scroll down. I want to increase delay in hiding of nav bar. Please tell me how to set custom transition speed for navbar? I am using Bootstrap classes for navbar.

```css
.spacer {
  height: 125vh;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-hide-on-scroll navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light ">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand ps-5 fs-4" href="#">Abdullah Asif</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 pe-5 fw-bold fs-4">
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Work</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="spacer"></div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: What is `navbar-hide-on-scroll`? That's not in the Bootstrap docs. Does the demo above show your problem? Please revise accordingly. Take the [tour] to learn how this site works and see [ask] for tips on writing good questions.

Comment: FYI, you're misusing `aria-current`. It should only be present on one menu item. See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/navbar/#how-it-works and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-current.

Comment: yeah ignore navbar-hide-on-scroll just let me know ho do I hide my navbar not instantly but after scrolling to some certain point in my web page

Comment: You'll need to research that and ask a more specific question. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You could add additional class to the `nav` element, for example `autohide`.
Then in your CSS you would need to target this class and add transition duration property like so:

```
.autohide {
  transition-duration: 4s;
}
```

You could also apply this to all `nav` elements on your site by targeting the `nav` element itself:

```
nav {
  transition-duration: 4s;
}
```

Comment: It did not work. I think I want navbar to hide when I have scroll down some custom number of pixels like in JS we can set when we want navbar to hide like after 50px or 100px.